# Java System.nanoTime() vs System.currentTimeMillis(). Why do they have different outputs?

Tags: java, nanotime

Given the following Java code:

```
class Tester
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime()/1000));
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }
```

It gave an output of

```
2626051678558
1377785791569
```

I was expecting a little difference between the two but I was wrong.
Do you have any idea guys why it behaved like that?

Comment: As an aside: a nanosecond is 1 millionth of a second, so to get the output of nanoTime() to millisecond scale you should divide by 1000000 rather than 1000.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the method's [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not
>   related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value
>   returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but **arbitrary** origin
>   time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same
>   origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a
>   Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to
>   use a different origin.

`nanoTime()` is not showing you the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
       long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();     
       long nanos = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(currentTimeMillis);
       System.out.println(nanos);
       System.out.println(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(nanos)*1000000);
```

Comment: Wow! this is one useful piece of script for handling **milliseconds** and **nanoseconds**. However, it seems it's not that directly related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

nanoTime(), as the java doc says, is a precision timer. currentTimeMillis() is NOT A TIMER, it is the "wall clock". nanoTime() will always produce positive elapsed time, currentTimeMillis will not (e.g. if you change the date, hit a leap second, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Android, nanoTime is affected by deep sleep modes.  Use SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() (which returns msec) instead